# Careers has a nominal fee to weed out non serious applicants, and yet everyone can file for free if they want

Tags: discussion, support, jobs, students

From the [FAQ page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> **Why are you charging the job seeker? Shouldn’t the hiring managers be
>   paying for everything?**
>
> When hiring managers search through
>   CVs, they want to know that they’re
>   looking at active, serious job
>   applicants. If it were free to file a
>   CV, a lot of applicants that weren’t
>   looking for jobs, or who knew that
>   they had no reasonable chance of
>   getting a job, would post them, making
>   it harder for the employers to find
>   serious applicants.
>
> That’s why we charge a nominal amount
>   to file a CV. It is, however,
>   absolutely guaranteed, and if you’re
>   unhappy or don’t get the result you
>   want, just let us know, and you’ll get
>   your money back on the spot.

- If you’re a student, a 1 year filing is free
- 1 year filing is $19

Since everyone can claim to be a student, and that students can sign up for free, doesn't that completely defeat the "serious applicants only" reasoning?

Or maybe there is something I'm missing? For example an option for employers to only search non-students applicants. But then it would be unfair for students, especially since (if that's the case) they aren't informed about this (as far as I know).

I think it's better to have either everyone or no-one pay. Making only some people pay defeats the reasoning for which you are asking the payment. Again, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: wow, "asked 8 secs ago" and an upvote. Must be some sort of record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We love students.  We love that we can provide a service to them and hopefully help them get off on the right track in their budding programming careers and get them seen by the top employers who want to see them.

BUT, as you alluded to in your question employers do have a search feature that allows them to filter out students.  This filter doesn't exist to slight students, it's there because some employers aren't interested in hiring students and we'd like to make those searches efficient too.  Just so you know there's also a search setting that allows employers to find *only* students.  Again, the feature doesn't exist to slight "regular" candidates, it just makes searches more efficient.

To assuage your fears about candidates gaming the free student filing I did a cursory check over a sampling of the student candidates in the database and didn't find any funny business.  All the student candidates I saw were in some form of institutionalized education within the last year.  We'll continue to keep an eye on this as we amass a larger and larger database to make sure the system stays healthy.

To your final point about everyone paying vs. no one paying, right now we still think that the nominal fee for "regular" candidates is doing its job by keeping less than serious candidates out of employers' searches, so we're going to keep it.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I see; it makes sense now. Thanks for your answer and for the careers website!

Comment: @Kop: No problem.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that you can host your CV for free, but if an employer uses the provided search and filtering tools, you won't show up. I also don't think that Google indexes CVs (I haven't seen my public CV turn up in Google yet). In addition, student users have a big badge on their CV that says "STUDENT" - this discourages non-students from obtaining the free year.

Those two things, coupled together, help SOC work.

Comment: I understand they have the big badge, but students **do show up** in searches, so employers will have to go through them, and since they don't pay...

Comment: Would you hire someone with a STUDENT badge if they weren't a student or recent graduate? I wouldn't - I don't want someone who games the system like that working for me, no matter how technically skilled they are.

Comment: even if they are real students, since they didn't pay the $20 fee they may not be serious applicants, or at least that's the reasoning. So why not have them pay too? If they don't have $20 a year (lol) I wouldn't want to hire them anyway because if they suck so much at managing their finances it's more likely they will suck at their job too.

Comment: If you link to externally from Stack Overflow, it'll show up. Yours hasn't been linked to externally, or you don't have a public CV.

Comment: Oh, they do? I thought they were blocked in robots.txt. That's interesting to know.